# Get GeoJSON feature from a promise response in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, json

Openlayers 6.3.5

I am using an APIRest and a promise to request a PostgreSQL database :

```
const test = fetch(`http://...`)
    .then(rep => rep.json())
    .then(ope => {
     //ope in GeoJSON format//      
   })
```

I try to convert the response in a `GeoJSON` format to be able to get the feature with `getFeatures` method then zoom on it like it is shown in [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html) with `getGeometry` method.
Is there a simplier way to do that than re-start with a `VectorSource` and a `VectorLayer` ?

EDIT : here is a sample of a `console.log(JSON.stringify(ope))` :
(geom field shortened)

```
[{"gid":35251,"numope":"F000325","ro":"Doe, John","typope":"Fouilles",  
"nomope":"CERELLES, 37, BAIGNEUX, 02/360 - Tranche 1",  
"numoa":"5786","statut_contractuel":"Terminé","statut_operationnel":"Terminé",  
"operateur":"","amenageur":"COFIROUTE",  
"geom":{"type":"MultiPolygon","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3857"}},  
"coordinates":[[[[74795.90446955772,6021976.919442274],...[74795.90446955772,6021976.919442274]]]]},  
"code_tranche":"F000325-1","surface":11373.89,  
"date_fin_terrain":"2003-07-31","date_deb_terrain":"2003-03-17",  
"numoptiers":null,"typemp":"prescrite","numprescr":"02/360","date_prescription":"2002-12-11"}]
```

Comment: You do not need a source or layer, but if you read directly you must handle any transform between data projection and view projection yourself  https://codesandbox.io/s/center-forked-98yhlm?file=/main.js

Comment: It is the same projection cause I am the admin of the database and that is very useful !
With your example, I have `Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined`.

Comment: Are you sure your are getting correct GeoJSON response to your `fetch` request? Can you post a sample from it?

Comment: How can I post a sample of GeoJSON since it is not created ? All I can log is the `rep.json()`. But indeed it seems that the problem should be in the `GeoJSON` as far as I understand from some posts on stackexchange or from the API ?

Comment: By GeoJSON I mean GeoJSON data received as result of `fetch` request, like for example `const test = fetch(`http://...`).then(rep => rep.json()).then(ope => {console.log(ope);})`

Comment: First post edited and sample of data added.

Comment: Your example does not show much. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(ope))`. Valid GeoJSON collection should look something like `{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {"GEO_ID": "0400000US04","STATE": "04","NAME": "Arizona",},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-112.538593,37.000674],[-112.534545,37.000684] ...`.

Comment: you are right. Done with `JSON.stringify()` in the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not GeoJSON, but it has geometry that corresponds to GeoJSON standard, so you can use `.readGeometry` method to read it.

Code could then look something like this:

```
const feature = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readGeometry(ope[0].geom, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
  featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
});
```

Comment: Got it, Thanks.Then, I used `map.getView().fit(polygon)` to zoom on the geometry.